# Filter chain in URLrewrite filter

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm using Tuckey's URL rewrite filter combined with a Home grown security filter.

- The URL rewrite  filter is mapped over `/*`
- The security filter is mapped over '/*'

Also, the URL rewrite filter has the following rule:

```
<rule>
    <name>User</name>
    <from>^/user/$</from>
    <to>/user.do</to>
</rule>
```

For a request like: **myapp/user/** I am expecting this flow:

1. Mapped by the URL rewrite filter. The request URL (or Servlet path) becomes **user.do**
2. Mapped by the security filter. Validation and maybe Redirect
3. Reach the controller mapped over **user.do**

However, somehow the second step is jumped whenever Tuckey's URL Rewrite applies a rule. This leads to really unpleasant behaviour like accessing secured pages without the proper authentication.

Is there something I missed? Should I expect another behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do **type="redirect"** the client will be issued a 302 "temporary redirect" status that will eventually redirect the browser to the new url.

If you want the user to still see the old "**from**" url in the browser's address line, try adding these to your "security" filter:

```
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because normally the urlrewritefilter doesn't redirect the url. It's just internally forwarding it. Try adding type="redirect" as an attribute and your security filter will catch the redirected request.

```
<rule>
    <name>User</name>
    <from>^/user/$</from>
    <to type="redirect">/user.do</to>
</rule>
```

That worked for me before.